# Boxes and arrows connecting the steps in a solution?

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, arrows, tikz-arrows

Can someone please help me how to achieve this kind of solutions in Latex?
Thank you for your time.

I have been using Latex for quite a while now in writing solutions for my math classes. I usually use color coding and other nice features. I recently came across some writings as shown in the picture. They are more elaborate and helps my students understand each and every step. I would like to implement this and I do not know where to begin. How do I draw boxes with connecting arrows to the steps?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. The Question is too broad. What exactly do you want to reproduce?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I am new to the forum and trying to get accustomed. I added some information by editing the post. Please see if this helps you in answering my question. Good day!

Comment: Already start by writing the text in a left and right box so that the people who can help you are only interested in the problem and don't have to write an MWE for you. Read more : [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: Package [`tikzmark`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) may help. You can find usage examples of it in this site.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553135/197451

Comment: A very good question. +1!

Comment: You can take a look to the package `witharrows`.