# How draw multiple timelines one after another?

Tags: line, chronology

I am using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161285/127048) to draw a timeline. Is it possible to draw the following line?

```
         |--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|----->
block # 100      150      200      250      300      350      400      450   
         |-----------------|---------------||---------|--------|--------|
```

where it will increase by `N`(greater than 1).

When I try `\noindent\begin{markschronology}[50]{100}{600}{\textwidth}` from the solution it does not draw a proper line.

---

I have also tried this code which does not draw horizontal lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronology}
\begin{document}

\begin{chronology}[50]{100}{600}{3ex}[\textwidth]
\end{chronology}

\end{document}
```

---

Example sketch:

[image]

Comment: what is the end result desired -- a sketch would help

Comment: @jsbibra I will , can I also made few more changes on top of the orignal sketch?

Comment: add it below the original label it as an edit

Comment: @jsbibra Just did, I am sorry it is actually more complex than I asked. I can ask lists at bottom on another question for clearity

Comment: does this help -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553107/how-to-convert-this-annual-timeline-to-semi-annual-timeline/553135#553135

Comment: @jsbibra yes on top of your answer can two lined be drawen one after another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->, -Latex, line width=1pt] (0,0)node(a){} -- (12,0) node (b) {} ;
        \foreach \x [count=\i] in {100,150,...,450,}%
        {
            \draw[line width=1pt] (\i*1.3,-2mm) node[below](n\i) {\x} -- ++(0,4mm);
        }
    
    \draw[->, -Latex, line width=1pt] (0,-1.5cm)node(a){} -- (12,-1.5cm) node (b) {} ;
    \draw[line width=1pt] (n1) ++(0,-1.25cm)--++(0,4mm);
    \draw[line width=1pt] (n3) ++(0,-1.25cm)--++(0,4mm);
    \draw[line width=1pt] (n6) ++(0,-1.25cm)--++(0,4mm);
    \draw[line width=1pt] (n7) ++(0,-1.25cm)--++(0,4mm);
    \draw[line width=1pt] (n8) ++(0,-1.25cm)--++(0,4mm);
    \draw[line width=1pt] (n5) ++(0,-1.25cm)--++(0,4mm);
    \draw[line width=1pt] (n5) ++(2pt,-1.25cm)--++(0,4mm);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->, -Latex, line width=1pt] (0,0)node(a){} -- (12,0) node (b) {} ;
        \foreach \x [count=\i] in {100,150,...,450,}%
        {
            \draw[line width=1pt] (\i*1.3,-2mm) node[below](n\i) {\x} -- ++(0,4mm);
        }
    
    \draw[ line width=1pt, red] (0,-1.5cm)node(a){} -- (12,-1.5cm) node (b) {} ;
    \draw[line width=1pt] (n1) ++(0,-1.25cm)--++(0,2mm);
    \draw[line width=1pt] (n3) ++(0,-1.25cm)--++(0,4mm);
    \draw[line width=1pt] (n6) ++(0,-1.25cm)--++(0,4mm);
    \draw[line width=1pt] (n7) ++(0,-1.25cm)--++(0,4mm);
    \draw[line width=1pt] (n8) ++(0,-1.25cm)--++(0,4mm);
    \draw[line width=1pt] (n5) ++(0,-1.25cm)--++(0,4mm);
    \draw[line width=1pt] (n5) ++(2pt,-1.25cm)--++(0,4mm);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @alper please see if the answer suits the requirement

Comment: Can we color the bottom timelines? Can the arrow section be discarded on the bottom timeline line? Can the `|` on top of each section be halfed like on your answer on top of `0.5`?

Comment: @alper see edit -- for color add red blue color of choice -- remove arrow by removing `->` -- for removing top portion of ticks edit code as follows -- `\draw[line width=1pt] (n1) ++(0,-1.25cm)--++(0,2mm);` -- instead of 4mm i have replaced with 2mm

Comment: Can we also draw iterative two seperate lines below one after each other that has different colors